# In a *nix shell, how can I connect to another server's FTP and download a file?

Tags: unix, ftp

On server1, I have a file in /home/example.zip. On server2, I need to basically do the equivalent of:

```
wget http://server1.com/example.zip
```

But of course via ftp. I of course have the username/password/host name.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

The [man page of wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/FTP-Options.html#FTP-Options) says:

```
--ftp-user=username
--ftp-password=password
```

So you can do it like this:

```
wget --ftp-user=xxxx --ftp-password=yyyy ftp://gnjilux.cc.fer.hr/welcome.msg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [wget](http://www.editcorp.com/Personal/Lars_Appel/wget/v1/wget_7.html) a ftp file.

For example:

```
wget ftp://gnjilux.cc.fer.hr/welcome.msg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
wget ftp://username:password@server1.com/example.zip
```